# Updating the table cells is lagging when using drag down feature on HandsOnTable (using it with AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, handsontable

About :
There are columns in the handsOnTable that I have defined that are updated based upon any change in other columns. If that change is just a normal edit the columns that are to be changed are updated instantaneously but when I am using the drag down feature to update one of the columns the columns that are supposed to be changed because of this are taking time to update(lagging).

code snippet

```
$scope.handsOnTableSettings = {
        preventOverflow: 'horizontal',
        stretchH: 'all',
        minSpareRows: 0,
        dataSchema : {'x':'0', 'y':'0', 'z':'0.00', 'w':'000.00'},
        colHeaders: true,
        rowHeaders: false,
        copyPaste: true,
        afterInit: function () {
          handsOnInstance = this;
      },
        cells: function (row, col) {
          var cellProperties = {};
          var data = this.instance.getData();
          var keys = Object.keys($scope.stats)

          if (data[row] && (col == 11 || col == 10 || col == 9 || col == 7 || col == 6 || col == 5 || col == 4) && data[row][11] && $scope.stats && $scope.stats[keys[row]] && $scope.stats[keys[row]][5] && !$scope.current) 
            cellProperties.readOnly = true;
            return cellProperties;
          }
          return cellProperties;
        },
        afterChange: function (src, changes) {
          if(src!=null){
          src.forEach(function(src){
            if (changes !== 'loadData') {
              if (src[1] == 'x') {
                if(src[3] === ""){
                  handsOnInstance.setDataAtCell(src[0], 9, 0)
                }
                  handsOnInstance.setDataAtCell(src[0], 10, src[3] * handsOnInstance.getDataAtCell(src[0], 4) / 1000);
              }
              if (src[1] == 'y') {
                  handsOnInstance.setDataAtCell(src[0], 10, src[3] * handsOnInstance.getDataAtCell(src[0], 9) / 1000);
              }

              if (src[1] == 'z') {
                $scope.total = _.sum(handsOnInstance.getDataAtCol(10)).toFixed(2);
                  handsOnInstance.setDataAtCell(src[0], 9, src[3] * 1000 / handsOnInstance.getDataAtCell(src[0], 4));
                }

              }
            }
          })}
        }
```

version of handsOnTable

```
 "@bower_components/handsontable": "handsontable/handsontable#~0.31.2",
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what is happening but what I know is you should care about using `setDataAtCell` inside `afterChange` hook because `setDataAtCell` will trigger the hook and you may get stuck in a loop. Try debugging by checking how many time you go in this hook when you update a cell.

Comment: Hey @KBell i am not getting stuck in the loop because of the conditions that i have specified . Its just that when i use dragdown to update multiple cells than setDataAtCell function call are executing after the AfterChange function is done . Is setDataAtCell async ?? As in It might be moving to callBack queue and once the call stack is empty all the setDataAtCell are executed

Comment: Well. I dont know if it's async, but i guess not. Though the recommended way to set multiple cells at once is to use only `setDataAtCell`one time with an array of changes instead of each value (see https://handsontable.com/docs/7.4.2/Core.html#setDataAtCell).

Comment: Also, can you provide a simple fiddle or stackblitz with the problem you mention ? It would be easier to understand and try to solve you problem. ;)